# How to make a cell fade when being edited

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a Tableview which contains a number of cells. I implemented the following code to allow the user to edit the table.

How do I make the cell fade when the user initiates editing?

```
- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
selectedCell.alpha = 0.1;

if ( editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{[XC1 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

}

```
}
```

The current code I added in an attempt to make the cell fade doesn't work!

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
selectedCell.alpha = 0.1;
```

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I am not sure you can set the alpha of the cell like this. Remember, cells are recycled and do not "belong" to one specific index path. Maybe you should first run some experiments outside editing mode.

Second, changing the cell in the `commitEditingStyle` method just before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` will almost certainly do nothing. This method is only called when a change to the table view in editing mode is confirmed, not just when selecting a cell.

Also, note that setting the alpha of a view does not animate this change. You could try to add an animation before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
   cell.alpha = 0.0; 
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
   // remove the cell
}];
```

Maybe you want to link the effect to selecting the cell. This is best done by overriding `setSelected:animated:`.

Comment: Hi Mundi, 

Thank you very much for your response, although because I am a novice I am still a little stuck. 

I implemented your animation code before I called deleteRowsAtIndexPaths but how do I link the effect to selecting the cell? 

I have read about setSelected:animated but I am still a little confused. 

Could you help me further? 

Thank you!

Comment: You have to override this method in your subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Dear Mundi, my apologies for not replying for such a long period of time. I don't actually have a subclass of UITableViewCell, as I am not using a custom cell (or am I confused here). Is there a way of implementing this feature not using a custom cell? Thank you for your help!

Comment: No you are right. In fact, you could subclass the cell just to override this method, so not a big deal.

Comment: Dear Mundi, thanks once again for your continued help! Hopefully this time should be the last! I am still slightly confused though:
a) are you suggesting that I create a new subclass of UITableViewCell and only include the code to make it fade on selection? If so how would you go about doing this? 
b) or have I missed something in subclassing and there is another way of doing things? 

Honestly thanks again for all your help, I know it seems like a minor thing but you are really making a difference for me. 
Cheers!

Comment: OK. You create the subclass with the normal new file dialog in Xcode. Then you set the class of your cell in storyboard via the inspector to your custom class. -- If you still have problems with this, you should open a new SOF question. -- Please do not forget to tick the checkmark above. -- Good luck!